# How to manage custom number formatting in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, number-formatting, powerbi-desktop

How can I do custom number formatting in a Power Bi visual?

[image: Like in my picture]

I don't want to show all value as million. I want to put thousand for 1-day value, and million for 1-week value and year for 1-year value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power BI charts follow the principles of good data visualisation. That includes a scale that is relevant to the data with labels that relate to the scale.

In the visualisation, the differences for the values less than 1M are not discernible. The label with the 0M supports that approach, although it doesn't look great. But that happens when you have a chart with very large AND very small values. Power BI only supports one display unit and you selected Millions.

You may want to consider using a different visual for the data. Not all visuals to be shown as charts. If you want to show the exact numbers, then a simple table might be a better approach. In a sorted list of numbers, the digits in a number act very much like a horizontal bar.

Or split the chart in two and show one chart for values above 1M and another for values below 1M.

Or use Thousands as display units instead of Millions.

[image]